# ‘Twas good until ‘twasn’t

Tags: contractions, contraction-vs-full-form

Since society generally seems to want 2 condense & abbreviate the English language, why don’t we use the words “‘twas” and “‘twasn’t” (which is not even a recognized word, btw!!) more often than we do?

Comment: There seems to be a resurgence in the usage of 'twas since the year 2000 See Ngram. Surprisingly, it is associated more with AmE than BrE . 'Twas expected that 'twasn't is not a popular word anywhere. I attempted an answer but something is going wrong with the Ngram links. Ngram is not holding the apostrophes and spaces.

Comment: @Nigel - nGram never does retain punctuation but that doesn't mean you can't search for it. Have a look here. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=twasn%27t&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctwasn%27t%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctwasn't%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Nigel - Hmm... there does seem to be something odd going on. When I clicked on the link I just gave, it said none found. However when I clicked on **Search** a second time, the graph came up.

Comment: “‘twas” “‘twasn’t” reflect phonetic speech patterns, as do "can't and won't, which are not words either (Cf "gonna" and "wanna".) 'Twas was usually used at the beginning of a sentence -> *'Twas the night before Christmas,* but this speech pattern is now rarely used. ""Twasn't!" is used in regional British English as phonetic representation of emphatic denial (Also sometime 'Twa'n't' and many other variations) but this too is in decline as there is little demand to write phonetic regional dialect as direct speech.

Comment: I haven't seen that usage since Christmas!!

Comment: @HotLicks It's beginning to look a lot like Christmas... (Never thought I'd say that in July)

Comment: "Twas" is an outdated contraction. How funny, right? As for society wanting to condense the English language....Perhaps you mean create contractions in the English language. Once made, they usually stick around.

Answer (score 0):

My take is that it is not so much a matter of the language proper as of what goes with it in terms of connotation that is often quickly picked up or associated with a person as they speak, such as regional background or (not saying that this is politically correct, but it is observable as a matter of fact) what is called social class. Variations in speaking like “‘twas” and “‘twasn’t” would easily fall into that category in some places.

Variations of speech that are not standard language have for long stretches served, or been seen by some parts of society at least, as a *social marker* telling of, say, a less educated person. A speaker not wishing to be associated with such connotations (and conscious and capable of avoiding them) may choose to avoid some variations of non-standard language.

A speaker's choice of using certain features or variations of language
may also be a question of [register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(sociolinguistics)). Note how many people choose their words differently as they speak with family or close friends, "in the hood" (:D), within a special interest group, or with complete strangers on different levels; there would very often also be differentiating between, say, particularly respected persons, persons in a position of power or highly superior to the speaker e.g. at the workplace, colleagues and (hopefully not often) "all the way down" to the janitor and the person who was hired to clean up the office and take out the garbage.

Some choice of register may also be deemed inappropriate in certain situations, such as where formal language would generally be required (or expected), one example of this would be, for many times at least, in court.

Some would also consider many kinds of abbreviated speech to be just sloppy and overly casual.

To complicate the matter, things have not been the same in all ages. Speech that was perfectly normal in, say, the Shakespearian era could sound pretty outdated today. A contemporary speaker might employ contemporarily uncommon speech selectively to give their message a specific note, but in general, it would often just sound weird.

All of this would go to significantly reduce the number of opportunities to use abbreviated speech. That would obviously explain why it would generally not be completely absent, but still seen considerably less than what would be theoretically possible.